# move selected values form textbox to dropdpwn

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

**What I need:** user insert a movie title in the textbox and as soon as he/she click the button "move to selectedlist", the movie title should be moved into dropdown list (which shows the movie titles that user has selected) and the textbox should be cleared.

I searched a lot, but whatever I found was the opposite (insert selected dropdown in the textbox! which is the opposite of what I need).

This is what I have tried but not work (It works for moving selected options of a dropdown into another dropdown, however it does not work for textbox:

```
<input class="autofill4" type="textbox" name= "q27[]" id="q" placeholder="Enter movie titles here" />
<input type="button" value="Add to selected list" id="btnMove"/>
<select id="selectedItems" name="selectedItems[]" multiple="multiple" width="200px" size="10px">
</select> 



$('#btnMove').on('click', function (d) {
       var selected = $("#q").val();
       if (selected.length == 0) {
            alert("Nothing to move.");
            e.preventDefault();
       }
       $('#selectedItems').append($(selected));
       $(selected).remove();
       d.preventDefault();
   });
```

Any help would be highly appreciated:)

Comment: You need to build a select `option` element before you can add it to the `select`. You are just adding the text value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it like this using jquery.

```
$('#btnMove').click(function (e) {
       var selected = $("#q").val();
       if (selected.length == 0) {
            alert("Nothing to move.");
            e.preventDefault();
       } 
       else
            $("#selectedItems").append(new Option(selected));
});
```

Hope this works.

Comment: Great! very simple and clear answer, thanks a lot.. Just one more question: I don't know why it does not clear the textbox.. I need to remove text from textbox after it was inserted in dropdown..

Comment: I tried to check it as answer, but it seems I have to wait 3 more minutes :)

Comment: try this `$("#q").val("")`